# I have problems on Html file

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, text-align

Hi I'm making a website but I'm having two problems

1. My HTML file doesn't see my CSS file. My Html file is Website/html/index.html and my CSS file is Website/css/index.css
2. Even though i do `text-align: center;`(CSS file line:22) my list doesn't become straight line

```
My Html code
```

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>KK Kiralama</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="kk-header">
      <div class="kk-container">
        <nav class="kk_nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
          <li><a href="Hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda</a></li>
          <li><a href="Araclarımız.html">Araçlarımız</a></li>
          <li><a href="Iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
          <li style="float:right"><a href="Giris.html">Giriş</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

```
My Css code
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;}
html{
    font-size: 60%;
}

.kk-header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#191970;
}
.kk-nav{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.kk-nav a{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
Thanks for any help!
Also, I'm open to any advice on making this code more smooth.
```

Comment: you are using relative path. Use `..` to indicate the parent directory.`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">`

Comment: Your classname in the HTML is kk_nav and in the css you refer to kk-nav. The whole CSS won't be applied if you type a different classname ;)

Comment: Your list items (`li`) must be contained in a parent `ol` or `ul`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help i didnt knew the for different path we need to use `..` but i changed it now it works just fine and for kk_nav i made a terrible writing so it become like that... Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try adding two dots to your CSS path. `href="../css/index.css"`
Then for the alignment, add `display: flex;` to the kk-nav shown below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;}
html{
    font-size: 60%;
}

.kk-header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#191970;
}
.kk-nav{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191970;
display: flex;
}

.kk-nav li a{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="kk-header">
      <div class="kk-container">
        <nav class="kk-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
          <li><a href="Hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda</a></li>
          <li><a href="Araclarımız.html">Araçlarımız</a></li>
          <li><a href="Iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
          <li style="float:right"><a href="Giris.html">Giriş</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Mine main question were the 'link' problem but after the two dots it worked so i was having that difficulty for that. For the <li> i just removed them for normal <a></a> so now it works. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you are using class .kk-nav but you have defined the class="kk_nav"
please replace the hyphen(-) sign with underscore sign(_) then your CSS with work.
The corrected code is here

```
    .kk_nav{ /* using underscore */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.kk_nav a{ /* using underscore */
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

and if you want to make nav text in the center use li in CSS not a
like

```
 .kk_nav li{ /* using li not a */
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I just modified the list for normal <a href="index.html"></a> so that work with it so the align did work after this but i had question marks on my head but its okay now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your HTML file doesn't see your CSS file because you haven't given him the good path to the CSS file. Both your files are inside *Website* folder, but in two different separate folders. So you need to tell HTML to return to its root/parent folder (Website) and from there to enter *css* folder where he'll find CSS file. You do that with ".."

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
```

2. You made an error. In HTML you named your  class "*kk_nav*" with an underscore and in CSS you called that class with a hyphen insted of underscore. Change it and it should work. And if it doesn't, then call *li* instead of *a* in CSS:

```css
.kk_nav li {}
```

Comment: I couldnt find any examples for ../css/ to go different folders... For the kk_nav i understand my fault so for more smooth code i just removed <li> now it works just fine. Thanks for correcting!!

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm seeing your CSS file just fine when I load it on my machine. Alternatively, in your case, if your current path isn't working for you can set the path like this for example `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">`. I will mention this is the same method as your current path except you're just adding '.' in front of your current file path. This will tell your HTML file to look for the file you need in the 'CSS' folder in the same directory level as your HTML file (assuming you have your HTML file in the root of your working directory).
2. In your CSS file you have `kk-nav` as your class name but in your current HTML file, you set the class as `kk_nav`. The only other note I really have is I see that you're defining your font size in the 'HTML' tag of your CSS, by default that is set to 16px, if I recall correctly. If you want a bigger font for your code I would suggest the using body element as the best practice. for example: `body {font-size: 20px;}`

I hope this helps.

This is the updated HTML code I used on my machine

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 60%;
}

.kk-header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#191970;
}
.kk-nav{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191970;
}
.kk-nav a{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>KK Kiralama</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="kk-header">
        <div class="kk-container">
            <nav class="kk-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Ana Sayfa</a></li>
            <li><a href="Hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda</a></li>
            <li><a href="Araclarımız.html">Araçlarımız</a></li>
            <li><a href="Iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="Giris.html">Giriş</a></li>
            </nav>
        </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="kk-header">
        <div class="kk-container">
          <nav class="nav">
            <a href="#">Ana Sayfa</a>
            <a href="#">abc</a>
            <a href="#">Araçlar</a>
            <a href="#">İletişim</a>
            <a href="#">Giriş</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).